# How do we write JUnit for method which writes the output into a file?

Tags: java, junit

My void method writes the matter into a file.How can I write a test method for it?

Answer (score 9):

Ideally, use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  Don't have your method create a file, have it take a Writer (or PrintWriter or whatever) instance.  That way, you can have your test inject a mock Writer that allows it to capture the data being written.

If you aren't at liberty to modify your method, then you'll have to very carefully use your test class's `@Before`/`@After` methods to create an isolated environment for the file to be created in.

Comment: @Aneesh: What would you like to know?

Comment: The method takes Product type object and list of JSON s and writes into a file using writer that is specific to that class.How shud I write the Junit for thi method

Comment: Another option is to pass in the path and use TemporaryFolder as suggested above.